# Can't install firebase-admin with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, firebase-admin

I'm trying to run this command to install firebase-admin: `npm install firebase-admin --save`

When I try to run this command, I get the following error:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\MyPath\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\abbrev' -> 'D:\MyPath\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\.abbrev.DELETE'
```

I have tried reinstalling Node.js, I have tried uninstalling a previous version of Node.js, I have tried updating npm, I have tried pretty much everything online but nothing is helping. If I run the newest version of Node.js, instead of getting this error, I get the following error:

```
Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
```

I have honestly tried several GitHub threads for people with the same problem but none of their solutions have worked for me, so I am trying here. Can anybody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further tinkering with this, it looks like I finally solved my issue so i can finally deploy to Firebase. These are the steps I took to solve this problem:

1. First, I uninstalled firebase-admin using the `npm uninstall firebase-admin` command.
2. I reinstalled firebase-adming using the `npm install firebase-admin` command. This didn't seem to fix my issue, but you never know.
3. I **deleted** the firebase-admin directory in the node_modules directory.
4. I ran `npm` install
5. I installed the firebase-admin directory again, this time using `npm install firebase-admin --save`
6. I ran `firebase deploy` and it worked!

I don't know how many of those steps were truly necessary but in the end, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it using yarn it will get installed smoothly as I faced the same issue while using npm I ran
`yarn add firebase-admin` and it got easily installed