# Error when trying to install firebase-admin via npm

Tags: node.js, firebase, msbuild, npm-install, firebase-admin

I'm getting an error when I try to install `firebase-admin`:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\TOYANSK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-
gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\TOYANSK\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\TOYANSK\\Documents\\Projects\\people\\functions\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v48-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\TOYANSK\\Documents\\Projects\\people\\functions\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v48-win32-x64-unknown"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\TOYANSK\Documents\Projects\people\functions\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\TOYANSK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\TOYANSK\Documents\Projects\people\functions\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v48-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\TOYANSK\Documents\Projects\people\functions\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v48-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TOYANSK\Documents\Projects\people\functions\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\TOYANSK\\Documents\\Projects\\people\\functions\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\TOYANSK\Documents\Projects\people\functions\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.2
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\TOYANSK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\TOYANSK\Documents\Projects\people\functions\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v48-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\TOYANSK\Documents\Projects\people\functions\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v48-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.7.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.7.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\TOYANSK\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-02-09T23_37_53_013Z-debug.log
```

To solve this problem, I have tried a lot of things, with no success so far:

- I try to update node-gyp and node-pre-gyp
- I install Python and MSBuild Tools
- I follow this: [Why does MSBuild look in C:\ for Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props instead of c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild? ( error MSB4019)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092169/why-does-msbuild-look-in-c-for-microsoft-cpp-default-props-instead-of-c-progr/27631063#27631063).
- I downgraded Node.js: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/38994433-failed-to-install-grpc-version-1-0-1.
- And also I try to follow these steps:
  [Can't install firebase-admin with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932525/cant-install-firebase-admin-with-npm).

But nothing changes the final result. I use Windows 10 64-bit, Node.js v6.11.2 (it was 8.4.0), NPM 5.6.0.

A curious fact is that the error also occurs during the `firebase init`, which allows to continue even after the error in npm install.
Maybe for this reason `firebase-admin` has not been previously installed, even being in the `package.json` of the `functions` directory

Answer (score 0):

What if you try running `npm install -g windows-build-tools` in Powershell as admin, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42713948/772985)?

Your stack trace includes `node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\TOYANSK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build ...` which most likely means you don't have the `node-gyp` library installed.

The title of the question that answer addresses is **npm install that requires node-gyp fails on Windows**.